# owner, tablename, view name oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

how do I get the owner , table name and all view names created from a table in oracle ? I'm looking at dba_tables and dba_views seperately, but is there a way to join both.

Comment: You would also want to take a look at [(dba | all | user)_dependencies](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1066.htm#REFRN20053) data dictionary view.

Comment: What do you mean by "view names **created for a table**"? There is no such concept in relational databases. Views are not created "for a table". A view may select from a table (or from several). Do you mean, find all views that select FROM a given table? Then: Be aware that a view may select from another view, and this other view may select from "your" table. Do you also want this more remotely related view to be shown, or only views that select DIRECTLY from your table?

Comment: Thanks for the education. I mean views created from a table.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas! I was able to get the information that I was looking from dba_dependencies view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query. Enter the name of your table in upper case.

```
SELECT referenced_owner OWNER,
  referenced_name TABLE_NAME ,
  NAME VIEW_NAME
FROM all_dependencies
WHERE type          = 'VIEW'
AND referenced_type = 'TABLE'
AND referenced_name = '&table_name';
```

This would give you output of the form :

```
OWNER           TABLE_NAME        VIEW_NAME        
-------     ----------------- ------------------   
HR              DEPARTMENTS       EMP_DETAILS_VIEW 
HR              DEPARTMENTS       V_EMPLOYEES      
HR              DEPARTMENTS       V_EMP_DEP
```

**Note :** As mentioned in one of the comments, "*view names created for a table*" is not meaningful. It should be mentioned as `Views` that depend on a given table.